# View disappears when apply ConstraintSet in Constraintlayout android

Tags: android-constraintlayout

At the beginning, the ImageView is horizontally center. I'm moving the View to the left in Kotlin. After applying, the ImageView disappears. I don't have any clue to debug this issue

[image]

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        applyConstraintSet.clone(vConstraint)

}

  private fun startAnimation() {
     applyConstraintSet.setHorizontalBias(R.id.ivAvatar, 0.2F)

     val transition = AutoTransition()
         transition.duration = 1500
         transition.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(vConstraint, transition)

     applyConstraintSet.applyTo(vConstraint)

}
```

XML

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/vConstraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/ivAvatar"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
        android:scaleX="0"
        android:scaleY="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        fresco:roundAsCircle="true" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question today.
I fixed it by adding `id` for all children of `ConstraintLayout`.
It works for me in `version 1.0.2`